# Kernel Modules Created by DKMS Show "Exec format error" (after update to Ubuntu 21.04)

Tags: kernel, 21.04, dkms

Hi I'm in a weird situation. The update to Hirsute seemed just fine until I plugged my Dockingstation in the Laptop and noticed that I wouldn't be able to use my external monitors. Narrowing down the cause led me to DKMS failing to produce modules for my kernel, as also the NVidia drivers and VirtualBox were not usable anymore.

What I found out is that GCC and BinUtils on the system should match the versions used to create the kernel.

So dmesg output contains:

```
sudo dmesg

Linux version 5.11.0-18-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-049) (gcc (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1) 10.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.36.1) #19-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 7 14:22:03 UTC 2021 (Ubuntu 5.11.0-18.19-generic 5.11.17)
```

GCC version is:

```
gcc --version

gcc (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1) 10.3.0
```

And binutils is:

```
sudo apt show binutils

Version: 2.36.1-6ubuntu1
```

So everything seems just fine, even when reinstalling for example virtualbox-dkms:

```
sudo apt install virtualbox-dkms

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libcg libcggl libnvidia-decode-460:i386 libnvidia-encode-460:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-460:i386 libnvidia-gl-460:i386 libnvidia-ifr1-460:i386 libpython2-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libxnvctrl0
  nvidia-prime nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-460 python-is-python2 python2 python2-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal screen-resolution-extra xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-460
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dkms
Suggested packages:
  menu
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dkms virtualbox-dkms
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 761 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5.983 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/main amd64 dkms all 2.8.4-4 [68,3 kB]
Get:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/multiverse amd64 virtualbox-dkms amd64 6.1.18-dfsg-5 [692 kB]
Fetched 761 kB in 0s (2.382 kB/s)        
Selecting previously unselected package dkms.
(Reading database ... 237715 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../archives/dkms_2.8.4-4_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.8.4-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-dkms.
Preparing to unpack .../virtualbox-dkms_6.1.18-dfsg-5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-dkms (6.1.18-dfsg-5) ...
Setting up dkms (2.8.4-4) ...
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (6.1.18-dfsg-5) ...
Loading new virtualbox-6.1.18 DKMS files...
Building for 5.11.0-18-generic
Building initial module for 5.11.0-18-generic
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
Done.

vboxdrv.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.11.0-18-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxnetadp.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.11.0-18-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxnetflt.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.11.0-18-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
```

But now I see that the virtualbox.service is not running:

```
systemctl status virtualbox.service 
● virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/virtualbox; generated)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2021-06-12 20:05:44 CEST; 5min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 2331 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/virtualbox start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 12 20:05:43 icy systemd[1]: Starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
Jun 12 20:05:43 icy virtualbox[2331]:  * Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...
Jun 12 20:05:44 icy virtualbox[2331]:  * No suitable module for running kernel found
Jun 12 20:05:44 icy virtualbox[2331]:    ...fail!
Jun 12 20:05:44 icy systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 12 20:05:44 icy systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 12 20:05:44 icy systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
```

And the reason seems to be the module itself:

```
sudo modprobe vboxdrv

modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxdrv': Exec format error
```

So finally the question is what can I do to make DKMS modules run again?

**Update 1**

As requested here is also the output of modinfo:

```
modinfo vboxdrv

filename:       /lib/modules/5.11.0-18-generic/updates/dkms/vboxdrv.ko
version:        6.1.18_Ubuntu r142142 (0x00300000)
license:        GPL
description:    Oracle VM VirtualBox Support Driver
author:         Oracle Corporation
srcversion:     5EB879B583F3535AB3CD593
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
name:           vboxdrv
vermagic:       5.11.0-18-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         icy Secure Boot Module Signature key
sig_key:        23:63:30:57:34:DB:4B:33:E5:70:6F:95:8E:AD:BC:C3:58:DA:A9:35
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      52:41:92:C6:00:84:D2:AC:7C:CB:B2:18:72:35:91:2D:49:AE:5C:CB:
        B4:E6:48:00:63:B2:E9:30:3A:68:D8:EC:CA:58:B4:14:0F:4D:4A:C2:
        83:BA:70:3A:6E:B8:F2:07:7D:8A:5B:F0:03:C8:83:61:FF:F9:1B:0D:
        ED:53:85:FF:6E:4F:C2:8A:1B:B5:4C:DC:79:13:00:D9:F8:87:58:19:
        3E:F6:C4:BC:93:5D:9F:6C:60:42:B0:55:8E:A1:B5:9E:50:EB:0C:BB:
        92:42:82:BE:F1:24:89:C3:5C:CB:3E:2B:51:66:57:00:62:55:63:2E:
        D6:4A:10:47:66:4D:33:F6:0F:DF:02:A3:17:1E:34:7D:BF:64:99:88:
        E3:D2:18:DA:B9:39:13:BC:19:28:E3:6A:F4:51:94:41:35:E5:F0:C5:
        5E:61:A2:11:C3:1C:D4:4B:7C:09:64:41:C9:A1:D6:73:A2:5C:E9:FF:
        21:E4:A3:B7:85:5C:17:AE:75:1A:06:41:3F:63:3A:69:36:2F:3C:C9:
        4B:8B:65:FF:92:1B:00:67:43:37:32:91:9A:9E:A6:C9:42:EB:1A:18:
        A4:47:89:B2:E0:02:B8:C6:6F:DE:B4:D8:40:34:30:70:84:85:4F:C1:
        1D:B2:BA:BE:4A:15:73:6C:C0:99:DE:06:8C:E6:89:74
parm:           force_async_tsc:force the asynchronous TSC mode (int)
```

**Update 2**

dpkg:

```
dpkg -l *virtualbox*

Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                           Version                   Architecture Description
+++-==============================-=========================-============-============================================================
ii  virtualbox                     6.1.18-dfsg-5             amd64        x86 virtualization solution - base binaries
un  virtualbox-2.0                 <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-2.1                 <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-2.2                 <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-3.0                 <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-3.1                 <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-3.2                 <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-4.0                 <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-4.1                 <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-4.2                 <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-4.3                 <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-5.0                 <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-5.1                 <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-5.2                 <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-6.0                 <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
rc  virtualbox-6.1                 6.1.22-144080~Ubuntu~eoan amd64        Oracle VM VirtualBox
ii  virtualbox-dkms                6.1.18-dfsg-5             amd64        x86 virtualization solution - kernel module sources for dkms
un  virtualbox-guest-additions-iso <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-guest-dkms          <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-guest-modules       <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-modules             <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-ose                 <none>                    <none>       (no description available)
ii  virtualbox-qt                  6.1.18-dfsg-5             amd64        x86 virtualization solution - Qt based user interface
ii  virtualbox-source              6.1.18-dfsg-5             amd64        x86 virtualization solution - kernel module source
```

usr/src:

```
ls -al /usr/src/

total 900
drwxr-xr-x 29 root       root    4096 Jun 12 20:34 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root       root    4096 Apr 23  2020 ..
drwx------  2 nm-openvpn pulse   4096 Jun 18  2019 evdi-5.2.14
drwxr-xr-x  3 root       root    4096 Mai 14  2020 libdvd-pkg
drwxr-xr-x 24 root       root    4096 Jun  5 13:55 linux-headers-5.11.0-18
drwxr-xr-x  7 root       root    4096 Jun  5 14:13 linux-headers-5.11.0-18-generic
drwxr-xr-x 20 root       root    4096 Jun  5  2020 linux-headers-5.4.0-29
drwxr-xr-x  4 root       root    4096 Jun  5  2020 linux-headers-5.4.0-29-generic
drwxr-xr-x  3 root       root    4096 Jun 16  2020 linux-headers-5.4.0-31
drwxr-xr-x 20 root       root    4096 Jul  6  2020 linux-headers-5.4.0-33
drwxr-xr-x  4 root       root    4096 Jul  6  2020 linux-headers-5.4.0-33-generic
drwxr-xr-x 20 root       root    4096 Jul  6  2020 linux-headers-5.4.0-37
drwxr-xr-x  4 root       root    4096 Jul  6  2020 linux-headers-5.4.0-37-generic
drwxr-xr-x 20 root       root    4096 Aug  1  2020 linux-headers-5.4.0-39
drwxr-xr-x  4 root       root    4096 Aug  1  2020 linux-headers-5.4.0-39-generic
drwxr-xr-x 20 root       root    4096 Sep 11  2020 linux-headers-5.4.0-40
drwxr-xr-x  4 root       root    4096 Sep 11  2020 linux-headers-5.4.0-40-generic
drwxr-xr-x 20 root       root    4096 Sep 16  2020 linux-headers-5.4.0-42
drwxr-xr-x  4 root       root    4096 Sep 16  2020 linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic
drwxr-xr-x 20 root       root    4096 Sep 27  2020 linux-headers-5.4.0-45
drwxr-xr-x  4 root       root    4096 Sep 27  2020 linux-headers-5.4.0-45-generic
drwxr-xr-x 20 root       root    4096 Okt 25  2020 linux-headers-5.4.0-48
drwxr-xr-x  4 root       root    4096 Okt 25  2020 linux-headers-5.4.0-48-generic
drwxr-xr-x 20 root       root    4096 Nov  3  2020 linux-headers-5.4.0-51
drwxr-xr-x  4 root       root    4096 Nov  3  2020 linux-headers-5.4.0-51-generic
drwxr-xr-x 20 root       root    4096 Nov  3  2020 linux-headers-5.4.0-52
drwxr-xr-x  4 root       root    4096 Nov  3  2020 linux-headers-5.4.0-52-generic
drwxr-xr-x  7 root       root    4096 Jun 12 19:57 nvidia-460.80
drwxr-xr-x 11 root       root    4096 Jun 12 20:34 virtualbox-6.1.18
-rw-r--r--  1 root       root  802665 Apr  8 20:43 virtualbox.tar.bz2
```

modules:

```
ls -al /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/updates/dkms

total 680
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Jun 12 20:34 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Jun 12 20:34 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 620706 Jun 12 20:34 vboxdrv.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  17474 Jun 12 20:34 vboxnetadp.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  44378 Jun 12 20:34 vboxnetflt.ko
```

dkms status:

```
dkms status

virtualbox, 6.1.18, 5.11.0-18-generic, x86_64: installed
```

**Update 3**

The following command showed no results:

```
grep -i virtualbox /etc/apt/sources.list
```

In sources.list.d:

```
grep -i virtualbox /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian hirsute contrib
```

Well I will delete this file since installing virtualbox-6.1 is not working anyways. But I think the root cause is still DKMS since I have the same problem with for example evdi.ko when installing from DisplayLink driver from synaptics.com.

Synaptics shows me `virtualbox` and `virtualbox-6.1` only. After removing `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list` only `virtualbox` is left.

Reinstalled dkms and virtualbox. Still the same problem.

**Update 4**

Turns out I cannot even build a kernel module without dkms, so something is really bad.

Tried this tutorial [Writing a Simple Linux Kernel Module](https://blog.sourcerer.io/writing-a-simple-linux-kernel-module-d9dc3762c234)

Here is what I got:

```
user@icy:~/src/lkm-example$ make

make -C /lib/modules/5.11.0-18-generic/build M=/home/user/src/lkm-example modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.11.0-18-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/user/src/lkm-example/lkm-example/lkm_example.o
  MODPOST /home/user/src/lkm-example/lkm-example/Module.symvers
  CC [M]  /home/user/src/lkm-example/lkm-example/lkm_example.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/user/src/lkm-example/lkm-example/lkm_example.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.11.0-18-generic'

user@icy:~/src/lkm-example$ sudo insmod lkm_example.ko
[sudo] password for user:

insmod: ERROR: could not insert module lkm_example.ko: Invalid module format

user@icy:~/src/lkm-example$ modinfo lkm_example.ko

filename:       /home/user/src/lkm-example/lkm_example.ko
version:        0.01
description:    A simple example Linux module.
author:         Robert W. Oliver II
license:        GPL
srcversion:     0EC24E04A8469A9DB84342D
```

depends:
retpoline:      Y
name:           lkm_example
vermagic:       5.11.0-18-generic SMP mod_unload modversions

**Update 5 - Current State**

user@icy:~$ modinfo vboxdrv

```
filename:       /lib/modules/5.11.0-18-generic/updates/dkms/vboxdrv.ko
version:        6.1.18_Ubuntu r142142 (0x00300000)
license:        GPL
description:    Oracle VM VirtualBox Support Driver
author:         Oracle Corporation
srcversion:     5EB879B583F3535AB3CD593
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
name:           vboxdrv
vermagic:       5.11.0-18-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         icy Secure Boot Module Signature key
sig_key:        23:63:30:57:34:DB:4B:33:E5:70:6F:95:8E:AD:BC:C3:58:DA:A9:35
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      52:41:92:C6:00:84:D2:AC:7C:CB:B2:18:72:35:91:2D:49:AE:5C:CB:
        B4:E6:48:00:63:B2:E9:30:3A:68:D8:EC:CA:58:B4:14:0F:4D:4A:C2:
        83:BA:70:3A:6E:B8:F2:07:7D:8A:5B:F0:03:C8:83:61:FF:F9:1B:0D:
        ED:53:85:FF:6E:4F:C2:8A:1B:B5:4C:DC:79:13:00:D9:F8:87:58:19:
        3E:F6:C4:BC:93:5D:9F:6C:60:42:B0:55:8E:A1:B5:9E:50:EB:0C:BB:
        92:42:82:BE:F1:24:89:C3:5C:CB:3E:2B:51:66:57:00:62:55:63:2E:
        D6:4A:10:47:66:4D:33:F6:0F:DF:02:A3:17:1E:34:7D:BF:64:99:88:
        E3:D2:18:DA:B9:39:13:BC:19:28:E3:6A:F4:51:94:41:35:E5:F0:C5:
        5E:61:A2:11:C3:1C:D4:4B:7C:09:64:41:C9:A1:D6:73:A2:5C:E9:FF:
        21:E4:A3:B7:85:5C:17:AE:75:1A:06:41:3F:63:3A:69:36:2F:3C:C9:
        4B:8B:65:FF:92:1B:00:67:43:37:32:91:9A:9E:A6:C9:42:EB:1A:18:
        A4:47:89:B2:E0:02:B8:C6:6F:DE:B4:D8:40:34:30:70:84:85:4F:C1:
        1D:B2:BA:BE:4A:15:73:6C:C0:99:DE:06:8C:E6:89:74
parm:           force_async_tsc:force the asynchronous TSC mode (int)
```

user@icy:~$ dpkg -l *virtualbox*

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                           Version       Architecture Description
+++-==============================-=============-============-==========================================>
ii  virtualbox                     6.1.18-dfsg-5 amd64        x86 virtualization solution - base binaries
un  virtualbox-2.0                 <none>        <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-2.1                 <none>        <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-2.2                 <none>        <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-3.0                 <none>        <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-3.1                 <none>        <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-3.2                 <none>        <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-4.0                 <none>        <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-4.1                 <none>        <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-4.2                 <none>        <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-4.3                 <none>        <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-5.0                 <none>        <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-5.1                 <none>        <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-5.2                 <none>        <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-6.0                 <none>        <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-6.1                 <none>        <none>       (no description available)
ii  virtualbox-dkms                6.1.18-dfsg-5 amd64        x86 virtualization solution - kernel modul>
un  virtualbox-guest-additions-iso <none>        <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-guest-dkms          <none>        <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-guest-modules       <none>        <none>       (no description available)
un  virtualbox-modules             <none>        <none>       (no description available)
ii  virtualbox-qt                  6.1.18-dfsg-5 amd64        x86 virtualization solution - Qt based use>
un  virtualbox-source              <none>        <none>       (no description available)
```

user@icy:~$ ls -al /usr/src/

```
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4096 Jun 13 10:51 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4096 Apr 23  2020 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Mai 14  2020 libdvd-pkg
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Jun  5 13:55 linux-headers-5.11.0-18
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Jun  5 14:13 linux-headers-5.11.0-18-generic
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4096 Jun 13 10:51 virtualbox-6.1.18
```

user@icy:~$ ls -al /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/updates/dkms

```
total 680
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Jun 13 10:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Jun 13 10:52 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 620706 Jun 13 10:52 vboxdrv.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  17474 Jun 13 10:52 vboxnetadp.ko
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  44378 Jun 13 10:52 vboxnetflt.ko
```

user@icy:~$ dkms status

```
virtualbox, 6.1.18, 5.11.0-18-generic, x86_64: installed
```

user@icy:~$ grep -i virtualbox /etc/apt/sources.list

```
<No output here>
```

user@icy:~$ grep -i virtualbox /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list

```
<No output here>
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `modinfo vboxdrv`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Updated question to contain output of modinfo.

Comment: Show me `dpkg -l *virtualbox*` and `ls -al /usr/src` and `ls -al /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/updates/dkms` and `dkms status`.

Comment: @heynnema Here we go. dpkg -l shows some weird ubuntu eoan package. Think that came into play when I tried to install VirtualBox through the instructions on their web page...

Comment: Where/how did you get your copy of Virtualbox 6.1.18? Show me `grep -i virtualbox /etc/apt/sources.list` and `grep -i virtualbox /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`. If you look in `Synaptic`, search for "virtualbox", do you see "virtualbox" and "virtualbox-6.0" and "virtualbox-6.1"?

Comment: @heynnema Got rid of virtualbox-6.1 now. But problem is still the same.

Comment: **You're getting ahead of me**. Please redo fresh outputs of ALL of the commands from my last two comments... **I have to kind of start all over again**. Leave the existing outputs in your question, in case i need to compare. Please describe the EXACT problem that remains now. You also didn't tell me how/where you got VB 6.1.18.... a downloaded .deb file... what?

Comment: @heynnema Sorry and thanks for the patience. Will update the outputs in about 4-5 hours. In the meantime. Is there kind of a minimal demo dkms module that I could build, to see if that fails, too?

Comment: @heynnema Turned out I cannot even build a basic kernel module. So even dkms is out of the game, not only virtualbox.

Comment: Don't get sidetracked or distracted by other situations... like 4+ year old demo kernel module tutorials. Since the demo compiled fine, and didn't use dkms at all, we can only assume the source code for the module was not up to Ubuntu 21.04 standards, or there's something else wrong in your system... which I'd still need to prove. Give me fresh copies of all of my prior commands, and let me re-determine where we stand.

Comment: What version Virtualbox in Synaptic right now?

Comment: Show me `python --version`.

Comment: @heynnema Python version is Python 3.9.5

Comment: @heynnema Also I don't really know where this version of VirtualBox comes from. Isn't it in the standard Ubuntu repositories? It's listed on https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/allpackages as virtualbox (6.1.18-dfsg-5) [multiverse]

Comment: OK, that's fine. You've done a good job of cleaning up your system, and updating your question. I assume that you're still having the problem, yes? Do this... boot to a Ubuntu Live 21.04 USB/DVD, and install `dkms` and virtualbox 6.1.18... or evdi... and see if you can then load vboxdrv or the evdi module. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema Booting a Live-USB with Ubuntu 21.04 was easy and showed no problems at all. Neither with virtualbox, evdi or even Hello World kernel module. Guess I'll do a fresh install then. Or do you have any more ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After performing various Ubuntu distribution upgrades, now with the installation of 21.04 you have a problem. It's not totally unusual that multiple distribution upgrades can leave the system incomplete.

Booting to a Ubuntu Live 21.04 USB/DVD proves that the problem is with your current installation.

Please clean reinstall Ubuntu 21.04.

Comment: Today I installed kernel 5.11.0-22-generic with the standard Software Updater App. That update seems to fix everything.

Comment: @mark Thanks for the update! Before the Software Updater, had you clean reinstalled Ubuntu, or not?

Comment: I did not reinstall. Just used my old Ubuntu 20.04 (bionic) in the meantime and gave 21.04 another chance later on.

Comment: @heynnema I have the same problem with virtualbox. 
Is there a way to backup & restore all data & settings before a clean installation of v21.04? Thanks

Comment: @Roey Please  start a new question.

Comment: @heynnema I'm using Kubuntu 21.04 so I thought it might be a better idea to start a thread in [Kubuntuforums](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/78294-Backup-ONLY-user-space-and-settings?p=447225#post447225). Can I open a question thread about KDE Plasma in askubuntu (Gnome) / there might be a bash solution to it?

Comment: @Roey Kubuntu is an official flavor of Ubuntu, so you can start a new question here.

Comment: @heynnema look here please https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360610/migrate-kubuntu-21-04-to-a-different-hardware-pc TNX

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after upgrading from 20.10 to 21.04 and managed to fix it without a complete reinstall by uninstalling everything related to module-builds:

- I removed all versions of build-essential, gcc, clang, binutils, libtool, autoconf, flex, and bison.
- I removed all packages named linux-headers-* and removed the corresponding directories in /usr/src.
- I removed and purged the dkms package and manually removed remaining files in /var/lib/dkms.

Then I reinstalled flex and bison (needed by linux-headers, but not installed automatically) and dkms.

Comment: this was nervewracking and a ton of work, but this solution fixed this problem for me without reinstalling :-)
I also made sure to re-select `linux-generic` afterwards. I am not sure it is neccessary, but it was originally installed, was then deselected by my removal of `linux-headers`, and It somehow felt inappropriate to _not_ select it again.