# Migrate Kubuntu 21.04 to a different hardware/PC

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu, backup, hardware, migration

I wanna migrate my Kubuntu 21.04 x64 OS from my current HP laptop to my new one.

It's currently in /dev/sda5 EXT4 partition on a dual-boot machine (w/ Windows 10 21H1 on /dev/sda3 NTFS) using GRUB

[image: Partition Table]

AFAIK I have 2 possibilities here:

1. Backup the entire partition using a 3rd party Windows app (e.g Acronis true image backup) create an EXT4 partition with 67GB+ disc space (w/ a linuxswap partition =RAM_SIZE of the new machine) and restore the EXT4 partition to that disc space
2. from rootfs (~/) backup all the apps,settings,configs (essentially all the installations & customizations I've made from the previous 21.04 installation including my user files (/home)) install a fresh Kubuntu 21.04 OS restore/override it with this backup

There are two problems here one for each option:

1. Can Kububtu detect and install the the new hardware on boot from network repos or Kubuntu bootable USB?
2. IDK if it's possible to create this kind of backup and if I can override a fresh one with it

Maybe none of the options above is practical or Maybe there are another options, Any suggestion are welcomed

Thanks

Comment: The best option by far - also the fastest - is to backup your files and install fresh in the new hardware.

Comment: @ChanganAuto what do you mean by my files ?? home/ and it's subdirs ? that's not what I'm asking for. **all the installations & customizations I've made from the previous 21.04 installation**

Comment: Cloning has never worked well you will spend a long time trying to get it 100 working. Good luck

Comment: I've had both terrific luck (*and issues that caused me to re-install*) by just taking out drive(s) from the old box, and dropping it into the new box.  My last change was <2 weeks ago, the replacement box was reliable with just drive added (*from old box*); just had some *screen tearing* when multiple videos were playing at the same time.. My box was a desktop, so I tried swapping out the video cards as well & issue was gone :)   (   Had I not have been able to swap video card (ie. laptop), I'd likely have re-installed as it takes <15 mins & you don't need to lose your config/customization!

Comment: FYI:  I did a QA-test today; where a 20.04 install was replaced by a *impish* install (what will be 21.10 on release); no user config was altered, no user file touched; and additional package(s) were restored (all were from Ubuntu repositories as that's all that is tested for in QA).  My install was Lubuntu, but it's the same with Kubuntu too.

Comment: Try dd command for backup and restore with the files of your choice, it might work.

Comment: @Roey Status please...

Comment: @Roey Status please...

Comment: @heynnema sorry I'm on forced hiatus due to holidays and a medical issue. Will check things out as soon as possible (can take time)

Answer (score 1):

There are so many variables, that there's no easy answer.

However, the BEST answer would be to do a clean Kubuntu install, reinstall your apps, and restore your files from /home to your fresh install. This would provide the BEST long-term results.

Another way would be to clone your entire disk, Windows and Kubuntu, to the new disk, adjust partition sizes if required, and make adjustments if required. There's a good chance that Windows will require repairs to be able to properly boot.

Messing with Windows backups, and trying to piece together what you had before is only for the very experienced user, and is still subject to problems.

Do a clean Kubuntu install.

The easy way to reinstall your apps is to use `Synaptic` download script...

[image]

The easy way to copy over your /home files is to back them up to a flash drive or external disk, and restore them on the new system.

Your swap shouldn't be a *swap partition equal to RAM size*. It should be a /swapfile sized to your configuration and usage pattern. Typically 4G is enough.